# Cannot move wine application window in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, wine

I have a problem with wine on my kubuntu installation.
When I open an **.exe** application I can resize the window of the application. My problem is that I can't move the window of the application.

I have tried to update the wine to the latest, now no more updates are available.That did not resolve the issue.

Any idea?

Comment: I too am a Kubuntu guy. Please edit your question.  What Kubuntu are you on. 18.04 or 20.04.  What version of wine are you running.  In Muon Package manager you need to have the wine-stable version 3.01-1 and Q4 wine.  Let me know or link me the application and I can replicate.

Comment: Hi Walttheboss, thanks for your reply. Im using Kubuntu 20.04 and wine version 5.0-3ubuntu1 from software center

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you tell me what program you are trying to run.  Then I can try to mimic the situation.

Comment: we try to open efficient pim (latest version)

Comment: Same problem here on Debian 10.